# Big query error: 403 Exceeded rate limits: too many table update operations for this table, but only 1 update being run

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-run

I have a cloud run container running that collects data from an API, formats it into a pandas dataframe, and then overwrites a big query table on a daily basis, using the pandas-gbq libary.
The code that updates the table is this:

```
pandas_gbq.to_gbq(
    df,
    table,
    table_schema=schema,
    if_exists="replace",
    project_id=project_id
)


print("table added to BQ")
```

The table is not large, around 100,000 rows and 30 columns.

This is the error:

```
google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 Exceeded rate limits: too many table update operations for this table. For more information, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors
at result (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/future/polling.py:134)
at result (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/job/base.py:679)
at load_chunks (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas_gbq/load.py:78)
at load_data (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas_gbq/gbq.py:629)
```

and this

```
pandas_gbq.gbq.GenericGBQException: Reason: 403 Exceeded rate limits: too many table update operations for this table. For more information, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors
at process_http_error (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas_gbq/gbq.py:435)
at load_data (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas_gbq/gbq.py:636)
at to_gbq (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas_gbq/gbq.py:1202)
at gift_purchases_and_promos (/app/main.py:240)
at dispatch_request (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py:1936)
at full_dispatch_request (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py:1950)
at reraise (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py:39)
at handle_user_exception (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py:1821)
at full_dispatch_request (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py:1952)
at wsgi_app (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py:2447)
at reraise (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py:39)
at handle_exception (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py:1867)
at wsgi_app (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py:2450)
at __call__ (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py:2464)
```

I was getting this error previously, and as a result I lowered the number of CPUs from 2 to 1 and that stopped the error from firing, but now I'm seeing it reappear. Are there any reasons for this error firing?

Comment: How many time did you run this script?

Comment: It's scheduled to run once every 24 hours. For some reason, when I leave to be triggered by cloud scheduler it errors more frequently, but when it run it manually via cloud scheduler (i.e. pressing "Run Now") it normally seems fine.

Comment: How long takes the processing? When you run the scheduler manually, what's the status of the job? Success or Fail?

Comment: The function takes around 3300 seconds to complete so nearing the limit. When I run the scheduler manually, the schedule job fails, but the cloud run job completes and finishes with a 200 status. The last couple of days, the process has completed automatically, so that's good, but it's still an intermittent error that doesn't make sense to me.